# Outlook 2010 and error 0x8004011d

Tags: exchange-2010, outlook-2010

My Exchange server is 2010 and all the clients that connect to it Windows 7 + Outlook 2010 Pro. One of those clients is failing to connect returning 0x8004011d. I tried Microsoft's [suggestion](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/289971/en) with no result.

Any ideas would be welcome.

EDIT: The fact that one of the clients was experiencing the problem was due to the rest of them not having tried to log in yet (this is a small installation).

Comment: Is the client using cached mode? If so, have you tried disabling cached mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually after a reboot a few of the Microsoft Exchange Services that were marked as "Automatic" in the Services tab, had not actually started, thus causing the trouble. Starting them manually fixed the problem

Comment: Which means that it is possible to avoid this by changing them from Automatic, to Automatic with delayed start.